# How to run lm for each subset of the data frame, and then aggreage the result?

Tags: r, lm

I have a big data frame df, with columns named as :

```
age, income, country
```

what I want to do is very simpe actually, do

```
fitFunc<-function(thisCountry){
    subframe<-df[which(country==thisCountry)];
    fit<-lm(income~0+age, data=subframe);
    return(coef(fit));
}
```

for each individual country. Then aggregate the result into a new data frame looks like :

```
    countryname,  coeffname
1      USA         1.2
2      GB          1.0
3      France      1.1
```

I tried to do :

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(allRics[1:5], fitit))
```

but i don know what to do next.

Can anyone help?

thanks!

Comment: I didn't know this... apparently `lm` has a `subset` option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328003/how-does-the-subset-argument-work-in-the-lm-function?rq=1 Look at the other "related links" to the right.

Comment: And what is a problem? Little tip - add comma to `subframe<-df[which(country==thisCountry),]`, otherwise this line should return error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
    set.seed(1)
    df<-data.frame(income=rnorm(100,100,20),age=rnorm(100,40,10),country=factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=T),levels=1:3,labels=c("us","gb","france")))

    out<-lapply(levels(df$country) , function(z) {
        data.frame(country=z, age= coef(lm(income~0+age, data=df[df$country==z,])),row.names=NULL)
    })
do.call(rbind ,out)
```

Comment: thanks for your help! but this only gives out a single column data frame, right? How to bind the country column with the output? do you know?

Comment: edited answer to include country

Answer (score 2):

Using @user20650's example data, this seems to produce the same result:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,list(age=lm(income~0+age)$coef),by=country]

#    country      age
# 1:      gb 2.428830
# 2:      us 2.540879
# 3:  france 2.369560
```

You'll need to install the `data.table` package first.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `plyr` package is created for tasks like this. It performs a function on a subset of the data and returns the results in a prespicified form. Using `ddply` we enter a data frame and get a data frame with the results back. See `plyr` example sessions and help files to learn more about this. It is well worth the effort to get acquanted with this package! 
See http://plyr.had.co.nz/ for a start.

```
library(plyr)
age <- runif(1000, 18, 80)
income <- 2000 + age*100 + rnorm(1000,0, 2000)
country <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:10], 1000, replace = T))
dat <- data.frame(age, income, country)

get.coef <- function(dat) lm(income ~ 0 + age, dat)$coefficients

ddply(dat, .(country), get.coef)
```