# Run lm() function over subsets of 2 different variables in data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, apply, linear-regression

I would like to create a function (preferably with an `apply` family function, that runs an `lm` function over subsets of data from two separate variables in a data frame. For reference, my data is currently structured as follows (this is a dummy data frame that is generally representative of the real data frame I'm working with):

```
District = c(rep("A", times = 25),
             rep("B", times = 25),
             rep("C", times = 25),
             rep("D", times = 25))

Year = c(1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975,
         1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975,
         1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975,
         1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975,
         1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975, 1971:1975)

Crop = c(rep("Wheat",  times = 5),
         rep("Maize",  times = 5),
         rep("Rice",   times = 5),
         rep("Barley", times = 5))

set.seed(100)
Yield = rnorm(100, 2, 0.5)

df <- data.frame(District, Year, Crop, Yield)
```

I need to generate a linear model (`lm`) predicting `Yield` as a function of `Year` for each `Crop` on a per-`District` basis. So, I need a model for Wheat in each district, Barley in each district, and so on. I need to automate this to the extent possible as my real data will result in approximately 7000 linear models.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633921/how-to-run-lm-for-each-subset-of-the-data-frame-and-then-aggreage-the-result) by [James Bond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209490/james-bond) to be very helpful as a point of departure. It is very elegant and uses `lapply`, which I would like to do as well, if possible (7000 linear models = very slow). However, it is only subsetting a SINGLE column in the dataset, whereas I need to subset two variables for each model. Here is my current (non-working) code modified to run on the above dummy dataset:

```
df$Dist <- as.factor(df$Dist)
df$Crop <- as.factor(df$Crop)

for (i in 1:length(levels(df$Crop))) {
  x <- levels(df$Crop)[i]
  dat <- df[df$Crop == x, ]
  out <- lapply(levels(dat$Dist), function(z) {
            data.frame(District = z, 
                       Slope = lm(Yield ~ Year, data = dat[dat$Dist == z, ])$coef[2], 
                       Crop = x,
                       row.names=NULL)
  })
}

do.call(rbind ,out)
```

Unfortunately, running the above code only generates a model for the first `Crop` level in the dataset (Wheat). See the output below:

```
  District       Slope  Crop
1        A  0.03125866 Wheat
2        B -0.08108222 Wheat
3        C  0.17172314 Wheat
4        D -0.11278486 Wheat
```

Any help in being able to loop over both the `Crop` and the `District` variable would be much appreciated. It seems like I'm close, but seem to missing something fundamental about the for loop.

If it is possible to pass 2 arguments to the `lapply` function and avoid the `for` loop altogether, that would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try subset argument inside lm function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using **dplyr**:

```
df_lm <- df %>%
  group_by(District,Crop) %>%
  do(mod = lm(Yield ~ Year,data = .))

df_coef <- df_lm %>%
  do(data.frame(
    District = .$District,
    Crop = .$Crop,
    var = names(coef(.$mod)),
    coef(summary(.$mod)))
    )

> df_coef
Source: local data frame [32 x 7]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 32 × 7
   District   Crop         var      Estimate   Std..Error    t.value   Pr...t..
*    <fctr> <fctr>      <fctr>         <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1         A Barley (Intercept) -407.66953514 378.49788671 -1.0770722 0.36034462
2         A Barley        Year    0.20771336   0.19183872  1.0827499 0.35818046
3         A  Maize (Intercept)  159.81133118 212.90233600  0.7506321 0.50738515
4         A  Maize        Year   -0.08002266   0.10790790 -0.7415830 0.51211787
5         A   Rice (Intercept)  -68.01125454 117.60578244 -0.5782986 0.60361684
6         A   Rice        Year    0.03552764   0.05960758  0.5960255 0.59313364
7         A  Wheat (Intercept)  -59.61828825 134.67806297 -0.4426726 0.66972726
8         A  Wheat        Year    0.03125866   0.06826053  0.4579317 0.65918309
9         B Barley (Intercept) -319.99755207  57.14553545 -5.5996947 0.01125215
10        B Barley        Year    0.16332436   0.02896377  5.6389189 0.01103509
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Another thing to look at is the `lmList` function in **nlme**.