# How to subset a range of values in lm()

Tags: r, subset

The help file for lm() doesn't go into the syntax for the subset argument.  I am not sure how to get it to find the line of best fit for only a portion of my data set.  This question is similar, but I wasn't able to solve my particular problem using it.  [How does the subset argument work in the lm() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328003/how-does-the-subset-argument-work-in-the-lm-function)

Here is my code:

```
    with(dat[dat$SIZE <7 & dat$SIZE > 0.8 ,], plot(SP.RICH~SIZE, log="x",
      xlim=c(1,9), ylim=c(60,180), ylab="plant species richness", 
      xlab="log area (ha)", type="n"))
   with(dat[dat$SIZE <7 & dat$SIZE > 0.8 ,], points(SP.RICH~SIZE, pch=20, cex=1))
   fit=lm(SP.RICH~SIZE, subset=c(1:7))
```

I would like to make sure that the regression line is drawn only for the values that I subset above in the plot() and points() commands.

Comment: I realize now that I should have asked how to filter values in the lm() command, rather than how to subset them.  I will try searching for more information on this now, but I will leave this question up in the meantime.

Comment: Now I am trying something like:   fit=with(dat[dat$SIZE <7 & dat$SIZE > 0.8 ,], lm(SP.RICH~SIZE))  but the line doesn't look right.  I am not sure how to include the fact that the x axis is on a log scale, so that I get a proper line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The subset parameter in `lm()` and other model fitting functions takes as its argument a logical vector the length of the dataframe, evaluated in the environment of the dataframe. So, if I understand you correctly, I would use the following:

```
fit <- lm(SP.RICH~SIZE, data=dat, subset=(SIZE>0.8 & SIZE<7))
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The line of code that you provided did fit a line to my data, but unfortunately it wasn't the proper line.  

So you have solved my syntax question, and I now know how to filter/subset in model fitting functions. 

Now I just have to figure out how to get the proper line.  Do you think that the problem might be that my x axis is on the log scale?

Answer (score 1):

But the above solution does not help if you want to run one lm for each group in your data - lets say that you have different countries as a column and you want to understand the relationship between richness and size within each country.

For that I recommend following the help for the function by in R http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/by.html:

```
require(stats)
attach(warpbreaks)
by(warpbreaks[, 1:2], tension, summary)
by(warpbreaks[, 1], list(wool = wool, tension = tension), summary)
by(warpbreaks, tension, function(x) lm(breaks ~ wool, data = x))

## now suppose we want to extract the coefficients by group
tmp <- by(warpbreaks, tension, function(x) lm(breaks ~ wool, data = x))
sapply(tmp, coef)
```

From the list `tmp` you can extract any lm parameters you like.