# interaction terms in multiple linear regression

Tags: r, regression

I have used the `lm` for my multiple regression analysis. and then used `GVLMA` for Assumption test, where the results showed that Global Stat and Heteroskedasticity tests were not satisfied.

the form of the code is as follows: (all variables are continuous)

```
model_1 <- lm (y ~ x1 + x2, data = abc)
```

Then I have run one more model with the same variables (thinking that I must introduce interaction terms fix the GVLMA assumptions)

```
model_2 <- lm (y ~ x1 + x2, x1 * x2, data = abc)
```

With this `model_2`, all the assumptions are satisfied. But when I checked I have realised the way interaction terms introduced was not accurate. I can't see what that 'comma' does here between the variables?

I am in a difficult situation as the model is fitting well, but I cannot explain what `, x1 * x2` does in the equation / results?

Please help me to understand.

Comment: Try `model_2 <- lm (y ~ x1 * x2, data = abc)`

Comment: Try `model_2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data = abc)`.

Answer (score 0):

With linear models the interaction term is defined by `:` and terms are separated by a `+`, so a model with the single and interaction terms is

```
lm(y ~ x1:x2 + x1 + x2)
```

However, you can write `x1*x2` which includes by the interaction and single effects so the following is equivalent to the above

```
lm(y ~ x1*x2)
```

See what happens when using the built in dataset iris, where the fixed effects are specified as `Petal.Width*Sepal.Length`, all three terms are in the model summary:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width * Sepal.Length, data = iris)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.99588 -0.24329  0.00355  0.29735  1.24780 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              -3.24804    0.59586  -5.451 2.08e-07 ***
Petal.Width               2.97115    0.35836   8.291 6.74e-14 ***
Sepal.Length              0.87551    0.11667   7.504 5.60e-12 ***
Petal.Width:Sepal.Length -0.22248    0.06384  -3.485  0.00065 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.3888 on 146 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9525,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9515 
F-statistic: 975.4 on 3 and 146 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

---

As to what the comma is doing in your models, it is creating a *subset*. Compare the summary of the following three models: the first have 146 and 147 degrees of freedom - they have have 150 data points and estimate 4 and 3 parameters each. The third model, one that mimics your specification, has 129 degrees of freedom - that's what made me realise it was subsetting. Checking the documentation for `lm()`, there is an argument for subsetting: `lm(formula, data, subset, ...)`. Because `data` is specified explicitly, the unspecified arguments default to `formula` and `subset`. You can also see that in the model summary, which shows a subset in the model call.

```
summary(lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width * Sepal.Length, data = iris))
summary(lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length, data = iris))
summary(lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length, Petal.Width * Sepal.Length, data = iris))
```

Your result can be recreated by passing this vector, `iris$Petal.Width * iris$Sepal.Length`, [as row numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328119/1040035) - so be careful, that's resuing some rows a lot and skipping a lot too so the result of this model doesn't match one that use all the data (and each data point only once).

```
summary(lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length, data = iris[iris$Petal.Width * iris$Sepal.Length, ]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I use lm (y ~ x1*x2), the gvlma results shows Global Stat assumptions not acceptable...Also VIF is very high....Hence I have used lm (y ~ x1 + x2, x1 * x2), then everything is passing...but I am not sure if this lm method is correct, and also dont know how to explain 'comma'

Comment: My specific query was what , x1 * x2 is doing in the lm equation?